# how to keep a column from a specific data set using data step in sas

Tags: sql, sas

I've 2 tables who has a same column of same attribute. I want to select that column and other columns from both tables. example

```
table_1

ID | column_1 | column_2
 1 |  col_1   |  col_2
 2 |  col_1   |  col_2
 3 |  col_1   |  col_2


table_2
ID | column_3 | column_4
 4 |  col_3   |  col_4
 5 |  col_3   |  col_4
 6 |  col_3   |  col_4
```

I want to create a table as

```
Required

ID | column_1 | column_4 
 1 |  col_1   |  col_4   
 2 |  col_1   |  col_4   
 3 |  col_1   |  col_4
```

I want to do it using data step

```
data required;
set table_1 table_2;
keep ID column_1 column_4;
run;
```

but it's giving me 6 rows.

I can get my table using proc sql

```
proc sql noprint;
create table required as
select t1.Id, t1.column_1, t2.column_4
from table_1 as t1, table_2 as t2;
quit;
```

I'm looking to do same with data step

Comment: What is your join condition? Do you want to match rows that have `id = n` in table 1 with rows that have `id = n + 3` in table 2? Or do you want to ignore `id` completely?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `SET` then the datasets are read sequentially.  If you want to combine the datasets record by record then use a `MERGE` instead.  Normally you would use a `BY` statement to combine the records based on some key variables.  But if you leave off the BY statement then SAS will combine the records in order.

Also watch out for variable name conflicts.  Both of your inputs have an `ID` variable. It looks like you only want to keep the one from the first dataset.  You can use the `KEEP=` dataset option to tell SAS which variables to include from a dataset.

```
data required;
   merge table_1 (keep=id column_1) table_2 (keep=column_4);
run;
```